# best way to handle ajax requests in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

it is a good way, to call php functions via javascript?

My POST Data looks like:

```
{
    0: [
        {
            "name": "function",
            "value": "toggle_user_status"
        }
    ],
    1: [
        {
            "name": "user_id",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ],
    ...
    ...
}
```

And my Ajax class looks like this:

```
<?php
class Ajax
{
        public function handleAjax() {
                $load_function = $_POST['function'];
                return call_user_func(array($this,$load_function));
        }

        private function toggle_user_status() {
                return '555nase';
        }
}
```

i know the $_POST var is not safe, but that's not the point. i would like to know if that a good way to call the function or not...?

PS: the url http://local.yolo/admin/ajax accepts only request from a logged-in administrator

Comment: Not ideally, what's to stop me editing your JS (with something like Firebug) and changing it to run `delete_all_users()` ? I know it's not that easy to guess a function name (you probably would never have the function anyway) but _what if you did_?

Comment: It's VERY unsafe. seriously. Let's say someone edits post data to call `delete` function. Do you want it? No.

Comment: You need to validate your input. The call itself is fine for me (not ideal though) - if you check the parameters (allowed functions, allowed parameters)...

Comment: @ex3v : i forgot to say: the url http://local.yolo/admin/ajax accepts only request from a logged in administrator

Comment: IMO it doesn't matter. You don't know if there are any exploits/backdoors that can end up in unauthorized access. Also there's factor of doing something wrong (for example calling another method) by mistake? And one more thing. From my personal experience those things seem to be simple at start, but they almost always grow up to big bowl of crappy code that you just can't maintain. I mean - sure, there are only few lines now, but function a will require some extra parameter - you will have to handle this, function b - another two parameters and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you aren't concerned about the security implications and that you're aware of them. Still, it's not a good idea. The reason is, your JavaScript must know the PHP implementation. If you changed something on your PHP side, you'll have to change something on your JavaScript side. It's better to *ask* the PHP software to do something, but you don't care how it does that.

For instance, you could define a public interface for your JavaScript, the public interface are URLs. You don't care how they handle anything, you simply want to get a response that also follows a public interface you defined. For instance for your example:

```
jQuery.post("/admin/user/toggle-status", { id: 1 });
```

The URL is the public interface at this point.

The user class handles things related to users:

```
<?php

interface UserInterface {

  public function toggleStatus();

}
```

The AJAX class handles the AJAX calls:

```
<?php

class AJAX {

  public function handle() {

  }

}
```

Separation of concern is important here.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the function that coming from js. use something like this:

```
<?php
    class Ajax
    {
        private $_allowed_functions = array('toggle_user_status');

        public function handleAjax() {
            $load_function = $_POST['function'];
            return in_array($load_function, $this -> _allowed_functions) ? call_user_func(array($this,$load_function)) : NULL;
        }
    }
```